# How to return a 2D vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector <vector<int> > pasTriangleUsingVector(int A)
{
    vector <vector<int> > arr;
    for(int line=0;line<A;line++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<=line;i++)
        {
            if(i==0 || line==i)
                arr[line][i]=1;
            else
                arr[line][i] = arr[line-1][i-1] + arr[line-1][i];

            //cout<<arr[line][i]<<" ";
        }
     }

     return arr;
}
```

I'm trying to return a vector containing the Pascal Triangle

It's showing segmentation error

Comment: The error isn't what you apparently think it it (returning the vector), but something else. Use a *debugger* to locate exactly where it happens.

Comment: A hint though: When you define a vector object, it is *empty*. All indexing into it will be *out of bounds!*

Answer (score 1):

The error is somehow not what you're thinking. There's nothing wrong with returning that vector. The error is about *accessing* that vector.

Consider your local variable definition:

```
vector <vector<int> > arr;
```

At the beginning, `arr` is a vector of size 0, or an *empty* vector. So accessing `arr[0]` is out of bounds. [operator`[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does not perform boundary checking. It simply invokes UB if you try to access out-of-bounds with it. Now you should get it: ***All*** later access to `arr` are out of bounds.

To make sure there's enough space, use [`std::vector::resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
vector <vector<int> > arr;
/**********/
arr.resize(A);
for(int line=0;line<A;line++)
{
    arr[line].resize(line+1);
    for(int i=0;i<=line;i++)
    {
        /* Your stuff here */
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you're returning a vector. The problem is that you're trying to access arr[line][i] without allocating memory for it.
That is the difference between an array (constant pointer) `int a[100];` and a vector `std::vector<int> a;` that defining the array this way is enough to allocate memory in compile time for it meanwhile defining a vector with default constructor will allocate no memory for it.
So here comes the solution:
There are many ways of allocating and reallocating memory for a vector.
One standard way is in the constructor:

```
vector<int> a(A, 0);
```

which defines an integer vector with 10 indices with a default value of 0 (you don't have to give a default value though).
in your case you can use the following

```
vector<int> temp(A);
vector<vector<int>> a(10, temp);
```

which defines a vector of 10 lines with 10 columns in every line.
That's what you don't need, since the width of the vector is constant in all lines so let's find some other way.
The first thing you should do is to allocate A lines which is:

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(A);
```

then you can use `std::vector::push_back()` member function instead of calling operator [].
that means

```
arr[line][i]=1;
```

should become

```
arr[line].push_back(1);
```

and

```
arr[line][i] = arr[line-1][i-1] + arr[line-1][i];
```

should become

```
arr[line].push_back(arr[line-1][i-1] + arr[line-1][i]).
```

Note that for every index you're adding, appending an element at the end, you will use this function only once then you can reach the added element from it's index using operator [], you can always use `std::vector::size` to get the number of elements in the vector as well.